# Get PID of process using some port

Tags: c#, .net, tcp

I need a way of, given a tcp port number, discover if there's some process using that port (and get the process id).

Something like netstat does but programmatically.

Answer (score 5):

This is probably too late for the original poster but someone else may find it useful. You can use the PowerShell class in the System.Management.Automation namespace.

```
private static IEnumerable<uint> ProcessesUsingPorts(uint id)
{
    PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
    ps.AddCommand("Get-NetTCPConnection").AddParameter("LocalPort", id);
    return ps.Invoke().Select(p => (uint)p.Properties["OwningProcess"].Value);
}
```